# Exception in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, sdl-2

I have see some topic on the subject, but i don't really understand...

There is someone enough patient to tell me how i can made this constructor correct?

```
SdlManager::SdlManager() {

    //SDL init
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Could not initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      goto error1;
    }

    //Init mutex for SDL access
    m_mutex = SDL_CreateMutex();
    if (m_mutex == nullptr)
      goto error2;

    try {
      m_display = DisplayManager(m_mutex, false);
      m_events = EventManager(m_mutex);
    }
    catch (void* _) {
      goto error3;
    }
    return;

    //Error Handling
  error3:
    SDL_DestroyMutex(m_mutex);
  error2:
    SDL_Quit();
  error1:
    throw ;
  }
```

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks
Have a nice day.

EDIT:

About the error :

```
src/sdl_manager.cpp:6:1: error: uninitialized reference member in ‘class sdl::DisplayManager&’ [-fpermissive]
     SdlManager::SdlManager() {
     ^
    In file included from src/sdl_manager.cpp:2:0:
    ./src/include/sdl_manager.hpp:13:20: note: ‘sdl::DisplayManager& sdl::SdlManager::m_display’ should be initialized
        DisplayManager& m_display;
                        ^
    src/sdl_manager.cpp:6:1: error: uninitialized reference member in ‘class sdl::EventManager&’ [-fpermissive]
     SdlManager::SdlManager() {
     ^
    In file included from src/sdl_manager.cpp:2:0:
    ./src/include/sdl_manager.hpp:14:19: note: ‘sdl::EventManager& sdl::SdlManager::m_events’ should be initialized
        EventManager&  m_events;
                       ^
```

It seems that my try-catch block is not good

EDIT2:

I just put the sdl_manager.hpp to be sure.

```
#ifndef  SDL_MANAGER_HPP
#define  SDL_MANAGER_HPP

#include  <SDL2/SDL_mutex.h>
#include  "display_manager.hpp"
#include  "event_manager.hpp"

namespace  sdl
{
  class  SdlManager {
    private:
      SDL_mutex*      m_mutex;
      DisplayManager& m_display;
      EventManager&   m_events;

    public:
      SdlManager();
      ~SdlManager();
  };
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ah yes maybe it's not an easy problem. Update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is not what modern idiomatic C++ looks like, and that's why it's confusing.

1. Don't use "goto" there's absolutely no reason here.
2. Use RAII idiom to simplify this stuff instead.

Basically in the above code you are using "goto" instead of using destructors. This is what code based on the RAII idiom would look like instead.

```
struct Sdl_error : public std::exception {
  ...
};

struct Sdl_Init_RAII {
  Sdl_Init_RAII()
  {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
      std::cout << "Could not initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
      throw Sdl_error();
    }
  }

  ~Sdl_Init_RAII()
  {
    SDL_Quit();
  }
};

struct Sdl_Mutex {
  SDL_Mutex * m_ptr;

  Sdl_Mutex()
    : m_ptr(SDL_CreateMutex())
  {
    if (m_ptr == nullptr) throw Sdl_error();
  }
  ~Sdl_Mutex()
  {
    if (m_ptr) { SDL_DestroyMutex(m_ptr); }
  }
};

SdlManager::SdlManager
  : m_init()
  , m_mutex()
  , m_displayer(m_mutex.m_ptr, false)
  , m_events(m_mutex.m_ptr)
{}
```

Note that you changed the code sample posted a little bit, but you should add a member of type `Sdl_Init_RAII` named `m_init` to `SdlManager` for the above code snipped to make sense.

Note that SdlManager does not need to have a destructor here because it does not itself directly manage any C resources. But, display, events, mutex all do. And Sdl_Init_RAII also exists, even though it has no member variables -- its purpose is to enforce the contract that whenever we call the C function SDL_Init we also call SDL_Quit later. Whenever you have a C lib that imposes some requirement like that its often a good idea to use an RAII object to make sure your C++ program lives up to the requirement.

Edit: Now that you posted the error message specifically, I can see that my refactor will also fix it. The problem is that, when you have a constructor with a member variable which is a reference, you MUST initialize it in the initalizer list, otherwise it cannot be bound to anything (!) at the start of the function, and the language simply does not allow that, prohibiting that is the entire point of references.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot to to show me this.
That's pretty interresting!

Answer (score 1):

The error `uninitialized reference member` says that you declared `m_display` and `m_events` as references. Those must be initialised in the initialiser list in your constructor like this:

```
SdlManager::SdlManager(DisplayManager& display, EventManager& events)
: m_mutex(nullptr)
, m_display(display)
, m_events(events)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was thinking that was possible to avoid.
Sorry